# Use Python to write to a .txt file column by column

Tags: python, networkx

How do you append a new column of data to an existing .txt file? Basically I'm generating 5 dictionaries and each time I generate one I want to write the values to a master text file in a new column. I'll display my code even though you won't be able to run it because it calls another program I wrote:

```
# Import personal module
import graphGenerator as gg
# Open file for writing data to
case=open(r'J:\FOIL\mediansandmeans.txt','w')
# Run code
for i in range(5):
    # create a graph using NetworkX and a code I wrote to read in an edgelist from a txt file
    G=gg.graph_creator(i+1)
    # calculate degree of all nodes using NetworkX--returns a dictionary
    d=nx.degree(G,weighted=True)
    # print dictionary values to text file
    for j in d.keys():
        case.write('%s\n' % d[j])
```

Now how do I have the program begin a new column for every dictionary?

Comment: That is some weird indentation you have there.

Comment: Please check your indentation, as python is whitespace sensitive.

Comment: Why don't you use a database for this? If you want to stick with files, use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) or [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) depending on what kind of data you are dealing with; otherwise you'll just have to read the entire file, add your column and then write the file again.

Comment: You may also want to consider building up the CSV in transposed form, so instead of adding a new column each time, you're just adding a new row (which you can do by appending to the file in-place). If necessary, transpose it when you're done, which means rewriting the file once, but that's better than N times.

Comment: Or, alternatively, keep each column in a separate file, and then merge them into one CSV when you're done.

Answer (score 5):

Text files are stored sequentially; line two begins where line one ends. You can *modify* material in the middle, but to add even one character (or to delete even one), you need to read everything that follows and write it again in its new offset in the file. In other words, you must read and write out the whole file, or use a different storage model (e.g., a database), as others suggested.

If you **really** had to add information to a file column-wise, you could do it by **writing out fixed-length lines,** padded with spaces; you then seek through the file and overwrite some of the spaces with new data. I won't provide code because it's a terrible approach: fixed-length records went out with the 1970s. And I really don't think it's necessary or appropriate in your case.

Looking at your code, I don't think you need to be adding columns to a file. I think the best solution would actually be to collect the values in a two-dimensional array, so you can write them out all at once, in the desired format, when you're done. Unless you have gigabytes worth of points, there's no reason to write them out one column at a time.

**Edit:** Since you like the array idea, here's how to create it and write it out easily:

```
from collections import defaultdict
degrees = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(5):
    G=gg.graph_creator(i+1)
    d=nx.degree(G,weighted=True)
    for j in d.keys():
       degrees[j].append(d[j])

for k in sorted(degrees.keys()):
    case.write("%s: %s\n" % (k, "\t".join(degrees[k])))
```

The "two dimensional array" is actually a dictionary of lists, in keeping with your version. (I take it that all returned dictionaries have exactly the same keys.) The code uses two handy python features: The `defaultdict` class saves you the trouble of creating each array row explicitly when recording the first column. And the output code joins the five values into a single tab-separated string for output.

Note also that unless you sort the keys of a dictionary, you'll get them in arbitary order-- usually not what you want on output.

Comment: Thanks so much, I hadn't thought of a two-dimensional array, I think that will work great!

Comment: +1. But if the keys are already sorted, or otherwise ordered in a consistent way, you can just use `OrderedDict` and skip the manual sorting. (There's a trick required to make a dict ordered and defaulted at the same time, but the trick is explained in the stdlib documentation.)

Comment: Thanks, @abarnert, good suggestion. But note that `nx.degree()` would need to return an `OrderedDict` for this to work. Anyway, there are other refinements possible with the code (e.g., no need to explicitly mention `.keys()` when iterating). I assume the OP is not an expert programmer, so I kept it clear and simple.

Answer (score 1):

As alexis explains, text files are not randomly accessible or modifiable. To insert new data into the middle of a text file, you have to write an entirely new file.

But is that really a problem? You're only doing this 5 times. And, since modern computers are pretty good at spamming huge amounts of sequential data to the hard drive, and not as good at randomly seeking and writing, the wasted time may not be that much. And this is dead simple. For example:

```
bakpath = path+'.bak'
os.rename(path, bakpath)
with open(path, 'rb') as infile, open(bakpath, 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row, newvalue in zip(csv.reader(infile), newvalues):
        row.append(newvalue)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

If it is, there are a few ways to improve things.

---

Most obviously, you can use a database (like `sqlite3`) or table system (like `pandas` or `pytables`) instead of a CSV file. On top of being already written and easy to use, they'll also probably be better optimized than whatever you come up with.

---

Or just use a separate file for each column. You can still access them almost as if they were one file, like this:

```
with closing_all([open(path, 'rb') for path in paths]) as files):
    for row in zip(*files):
        # each row is a tuple of columns
```

That `closing_all` isn't built into the stdlib, but you can write it trivially:

```
@contextmanager
def closing_all(things):
    try:
        yield things
    finally:
        for thing in things:
            thing.close()
```

If you need to merge them all into one file at the end, that's easy to do, and it means you're rewriting the whole thing 1 time instead of N times.

---

You could also build a random-access file yourself. If you know the max column lengths and number of columns in advance, you can just pad each column with spaces:

```
COLUMN_LENGTHS = 20, 15, 41, 12, 19
COLUMN_STARTS = [0] + list(itertools.accumulate(COLUMN_LENGTHS))
ROW_LENGTH = COLUMN_STARTS[-1] + 1

def read_cell(f, row, column):
    f.seek(row * ROW_LENGTH + COLUMN_STARTS[column])
    return f.read(COLUMN_LENGTHS[column]).rstrip()

def write_cell(f, row, column, value):
    f.seek(row * ROW_LENGTH + COLUMN_STARTS[column])
    padded = value.ljust(COLUMN_LENGTHS[column])
    f.write(padded)
```

If you *don't* know them in advance, but can roughly estimate, you can always use the same trick that `list` and similar classes use: Overestimate, and whenever you turn out to be wrote, multiply by some constant and copy over the old thing into a newly-expanded version. This means you're only rewriting the file log N times instead of N times.

---

Another alternative is to keep the file in transposed format, so you're just adding a new row instead of a new column. That you can do just by opening the file in `'a'` mode and writing to it.

If necessary, you can always transpose it back at the end, which means you're rewriting the file once instead of N times.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I intend to use this code to do this 133 times. ;) And unfortunately, I am working on a government computer, so I can't install any other libraries without a delay of several weeks while I get the Help Desk to authorize an installation and then perform it and hopefully get it correct. I only have basic Python.

Comment: @user2414615: `csv`, `os`, `contextlib`, `sqlite3`, `itertools`,  almost everything I mentioned, are part of "basic Python". (The only exceptions are `pandas` and `pytables`, which I mentioned in passing in parentheses.) If you're not using the standard library that comes with Python, you're not using Python; that's what "batteries included" is all about.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I was not aware of some of these (sqlite3 and contextlib). I will research into them more.

Comment: @user2414615: See http://docs.python.org/library/ for a list of all of the libraries that come with Python. (Make sure to select the right Python version in the option menu in the upper left.)

Comment: I don't mean to be pedantic, @abarnert, but **text files *are* randomly accessible and modifiable**: you can seek to any offset in the file, and you can read _or write_ whatever you want. It's just that every byte you write will overwrite the byte that was there before: what you can't do is _insert_ some bytes in the middle, and expect the rest of the file contents to shift down to accommodate them.

Comment: @alexis: No, _binary_ files are randomly modifiable. With a text file, writing a single newline character may write 2 bytes. And if you're using 3.x, writing any character may end up writing 1-6 bytes, depending on the character and the encoding. Because of these issues, Python (both versions) explicitly does not define the meaning of random `seek`s into a text file; you can only `seek` to the start, the end, or a value you got from an earlier `tell`.

Comment: @abarnert, good point about computed `seek`. Still, a file is a file and you can modify it at any point: you're just overwriting byte for byte. If you don't keep track of how many bytes you're writing, that's a very different sort of problem. (Anyway, in this particular case you'd be writing ascii digits).

Comment: @alexis: But you _can't_ keep track of how many bytes you're writing when you write to a text file. That's the whole point. Even just writing ASCII digits. For example: `f.write('1234')` might have written 5 bytes because `f.encoding` is some shift-based encoding that was in the wrong shift state, or 8 bytes because it's UTF-16…

Comment: But come on, who doesn't know whether they're writing ASCII or UTF-16? :-) I know you're trying to make a theoretical point, and I agree about the difficulty of it in the general case, but we're talking about columns of digits generated by networkx. You *know* it's not that hard to do.

Comment: Besides which, the UTF encodings were specifically designed to make it easy to realign after a seek-- you can always recognize a character boundary because the parts of the way the multi-byte characters are put together.

Comment: @alexis: If you know whether you're writing ASCII or UTF-16, just open the file in binary mode. Why make things harder on yourself by treating it as a text file and then trying to work around every single feature that distinguishes text files? Python is intentionally designed to make this hard for you; why fight it?

Comment: But I'm doing no such thing... Anyway, I think we've gotten a bit off track with this discussion ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It would be inefficient to append a new column to a text file. Either slurp the whole file in, add your column, and overwrite the existing file, or use something which has a native concept of columns, like a database, or xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it would be inefficient however if you must/really want to use files with columns, make a CSV with a `' '` delimiter like so:

For example, if you create a list for each row and then append each value you want for a column, you can write them like so:

```
import csv
with open('J:\FOIL\mediansandmeans.csv', 'wb') as case:
    writer = csv.writer(case, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(['your', 'first list', 'of rows'])
    writer.writerow(['your', 'second list', 'of rows'])
```

You can read more in the [csv documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

But really you should be using a database for this kind of stuff. Have you looked at [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)?

Comment: Thanks! As noted above, unfortunately I am working on a government computer, so I can't install any other libraries without a delay of several weeks while I get the Help Desk to authorize an installation and then perform it and hopefully get it correct. I only have basic Python.

Comment: @user2414615: The `csv` library is built in to the stdlib, so you already have it. Same with `sqlite3`. If you click on the documentation links in kisamoto's answer, they go right to the python.org site and make this obvious.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert - beat me to it. Yup Both [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) and [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) are present in Python > 2.5 standard libraries. If you have python installed just `import csv, sqlite3`